# Neutrino flavor models from irreducible representations of discrete groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, models

I am starting ph.D in neutrino physics-ph. I've read some papers on discrete symmetries and neutrino mass models. Neutrino flavor models are built using irreducible representations of discrete groups, or even SM is based on irreducible representation of certain groups only. Why is it possible only in irreps? Why can't we use any other representations (reducible, adjoint reps or any other if there is any)?

Comment: any particles or fields are defined by irreducible representations only. why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why do all fields in a QFT transform like *irreducible* representations of some group?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498124/2451)

Comment: oh thank you very much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do all fields in a QFT transform like \*irreducible\* representations of some group?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498124/)